# What is the bounding box of filtered features?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, filter

I'm using geoserver to store a number of gps tracks that are recorded during test drives with a number of vehicles. I have a layer defined that contains the following columns in the database:

- date
- point <-- postgis geometry
- vehicleID
- sensorID

That means that all tracks are recorded in the same layer. In geoserver, there is a feature to calculate the bounding box of the entire table. I'm looking for a way to calculate the bounding box for all tracks that fit a number of filters, say vehicleID and sensorID.

I would like to use this information to center the map over the middle of the selected points and to zoom in as close as possible (with all points still being visible).

The filtering is so far done using OpenLayers.Filter on a OpenLayers.Layer.WMS.

I'm looking for any way to achieve this behavior using geoserver.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WFS 1.1 (or greater) and make sure bbox generation is enabled, the feature collection returned will have the bbox in the header. Drawback, you also get all the data. Or you can install the WPS extension, it has a "bounds" process that will just return the bounding box of a set of features.

Comment: WFS works, but the xml data is quite large and takes a long time to load. The WPS extension seems promising, i've just installed it. I haven't figured out yet how to use a WFS query as input for the WPS. Do you know what data formats are supported?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to you to query via WFS?

Check this example: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-filter.html

When you apply a filter to a vector layer it is passes in the query so the returned features complies with the filter. Later you can extract the extent of the layer.

Comment: The filtering works (pretty much like in the example you linked). But how do i find out, where the center of the selected points is? In your example, that is done manually :/

Comment: Once you make tue WFS query and create a vector layer you can get the extent with: `layer.getExtent()` and work from it. See: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.getExtent